# Is the "Maximize data throughput for network applications" setting still valid on Windows 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking

On Windows 2003 you could choose between:

- `Minimize memory used`
- `Balance`
- `Maximize data throughput for file sharing`
- `Maximize data throughput for network applications`

These options used to be found under:

```
Control Panel -> 
    Network Connections -> 
       NIC Properties ->
           File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks ->
               Server Optimization tab
```

On Windows 2008 Server it appears you can't set this property any more. Do I set this somewhere else, or, are these options no longer valid under Windows 2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that this option has disappeared from the user interface. But it is still available as registry setting ([Microsoft Technet documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784562%28WS.10%29.aspx)):

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management 
DWORD: LargeSystemCache
```

and

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
DWORD: Size
```

I'm not sure if changing the default values will have an effect on the system.

> **Description**
>
> Specifies whether the system maintains
>   a standard size or a large size file
>   system cache, and influences how often
>   the system writes changed pages to
>   disk.
>
> Increasing the size of the file system
>   cache generally improves server
>   performance, but it reduces the
>   physical memory space available to
>   applications and services. Similarly,
>   writing system data less frequently
>   minimizes use of the disk subsystem,
>   but the changed pages occupy memory
>   that might otherwise be used by
>   applications.

```
Option setting                   Large System Cache value  Size value
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Minimize memory used                                    0           1
Balance                                                 0           2
Max throughput for file sharing                         1           3
Max throughput for network app                          0           3
```

Comment: Appreciated. You could maybe add the name of the DWORD: LargeSystemCache and this key: HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters, DWORD:Size to your answer then it's perfect.

Comment: Oh, I forgot the 2nd registry key. Done! Thanks Kev.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Server Performance team [say that LargeSystemCache is ignored in Windows Server 2008](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/02/01/ws2008-upgrade-paths-resource-limits-registry-values.aspx). The Windows Vista/Server 2008 kernel was modified to adjust the amount of virtual memory (in the kernel address space) allocated to each task dynamically, depending on the workload. That article states that the Memory Management registry settings were left in place for compatibility with applications that try to read the settings, but they have no effect.

It's not clear whether `LanmanServer\Parameters\Size` still has any effect. The `MaxWorkItems` value still has an effect for SMB 1.0 clients, but not for SMB 2.0, according to Citrix: [SMB Tuning for XenApp and File Servers on Windows Server 2008](http://blogs.citrix.com/2010/10/21/smb-tuning-for-xenapp-and-file-servers-on-windows-server-2008/).